# EF Core, Is it possible to use Data Annotaion for ValueConvertion?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I want to use Built-in converters as data annotation, something like this :

```
[BoolToZeroOneConverter]
public bool Flag {get;set;}
```

I neither want to use the Fluent API nor a custom converter.

Comment: looks like from the code this is not defined as an Attribute

Comment: yes in is not, I'm looking for a solution if exists!

Comment: If there was a solution, it would have been mentioned in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions)  (well, in 99% of the cases)